# Shortcut to make or toggle between the pascal and camel case in the Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to define a keyboard shortcut to toggle between the pascal and camel case in Visual Studio (2012)? If not, is any extensions existing for (e.g. is it possible in ReSharper)?

In the VS2012 you can use a Keyboard shortcuts for the lower case and the uppercase, so your myParam will be changed to the MYPARAM or myparam, but I need to change it to the MyParam.

E.g. a shortcut that changes isEnabled -> IsEnabled -> isEnabled

Comment: What do you mean by toggle? There is no "mode" in Visual Studio. Do you just want a keystroke that changes the case of the first letter in the word under your caret?

Comment: I mean a short way like a shortcut that can change myValue to MyValue and vice versa.

Comment: I think Resharper is your best bet.

Comment: Which resharper shortcut do you mean? Is there a toggle case shortcut?

Comment: @AlexanderZwitbaum Did you find a shortcut to do this for you? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too late! But [munyabe Case Converter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.CaseConverter) is a helpful configurable VS extension for the toggle you want.

I tried it on VS 2022 and according to the extension page assertion, it also works on VS 2012.